# WCF Service Works Locally but Returns 404 on Remote Server

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404

I have created the most simple of WCF services to try and learn the very basics.  When I run it on my localhost, it is working fine.  But when I deploy it to a remote server, it returns a 404.

Config:

```
<system.serviceModel> 
  <services> 
    <service name="MarathonInfo.MarathonInfoService"> 
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MarathonInfo.IMarathonInfo"
                behaviorConfiguration="Web"/> 
    </service> 
  </services> 
  <behaviors> 
    <serviceBehaviors> 
      <behavior> 
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/> 
      </behavior> 
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Web">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors> 
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" /> 
</system.serviceModel> 
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

service file:

```
namespace MarathonInfo
{
    public class MarathonInfoService : IMarathonInfo
    {
        public String GetData()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

And in the interface:

```
namespace MarathonInfo
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMarathonInfo
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        String GetData();
    }
}
```

Based on what I've found via Google I'm pretty sure I need to add a new endpoint, but I have not been able to do that with any success.  My remote URL looks like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/service/MarathonInfoService.svc
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:

```
address="http://localhost:10298/MarathonInfoService.svc"
```

replace it with the appropriate url when you deploy it on the server.

Comment: Argh!  I coped the config from a previous question and not from the actual config file  Here's what I've really got:

'<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="MarathonInfo.IMarathonInfo" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>'

Comment: Make sure the URL you use to reference the service is correct. Put a simple HTML file there and try to access it to make sure its not some permissions issue.

Comment: Ok, I changed the endpoint to the following, and still get the 404 error from the remote server:

<endpoint address="http://www.mydomain.com/marathanInfoservice.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="MarathonInfo.IMarathonInfo" behaviorConfiguration="web">
 </endpoint>

Comment: Did you try accessing an HTML page or an image or some other resource that resides in the same place as the SVC file?